# How to install bluetoothd 5.32 for ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

I needed to upgrade bluez to version 5.32. I've removed old bluez packages (4.1) with synaptic and installed bluez 5.32 from tar.xz. Now bluetoothd is missing. Where can i find the latest version of it?
I had an experience of installing bluez 5.30 in raspbian, everything was ok.

Comment: I just couldn't found bluetoothd. It was in /usr/libexec/bluetooth directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The file no longer exists in version 5

---

There is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Evidplace7/+archive/ubuntu/bluez5) with packages for Saucy … Wily

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

---

To install from source (Simply skip the steps that you have already performed)

```
cd
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.32.tar.xz
tar xf bluez-5.32.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.32
./configure
make
```

Install with

```
make install
```

or better with `checkinstall`

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```